# How to test our code to send 400 queries per user per minute in Gatling

Tags: performance, scala, gatling

I want to limit server calls to 400. For that I need to check if I pass 400+ queries will it give me error.

And how write code for 1 user repeated 400 times over a minute.

```
   val UIScenario = scenario("UI Simulation")
  .repeat(400)
  {
   exec(loginScns).exec(search)
  } 

  setUp(
         delphiUIScenario.inject(rampUsers(1) over(1 second)) 
       ).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Please help to sort out this

Thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: is this a web app ? there is tools for hammering web apps.

Comment: This is a web app. we need to test our server is gave error if api requests at the rate of GREATER than 400 requests/minute per user.

Comment: You have a tool, you have code ... where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For such as scenarios you can use Apache Benchmark tool. Here is homepage and documentation of it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/programs/ab.html